# How do I convert my Sudanese ICAO ATPL to UK CAA ATPL?

Tags: flight-training, caa-uk-regulations, atpl

I have a Sudanese ATPL with an ERJ-145 type-rating and 1858 total hours and 636 hours on type. How do I convert that to a UK ATPL?

Answer (score 1):

The information you're after is all on the caa website here: https://www.caa.co.uk/commercial-industry/pilot-licences/non-uk-licences/third-country-cpl-and-atpl-licence-conversion-requirements-from-1-january-2023/

In short you are required to do ground training:

> Full credits as regards the requirements to undergo a training course prior to undertaking the theoretical knowledge examinations and the skill test to holders of an airline transport pilots licence (‘ATPL’) issued by or on behalf of a third country in accordance with Annex 1 to the Chicago Convention provided that those holders have completed the experience requirements for the issue of an ATPL in the relevant aircraft category as set out in Subpart F of UK Part-FCL and provided that the third country licence contains a valid type rating for the aircraft to be used for the ATPL skill test.

Then you complete some exams and do a skills test

> Pass the ATPL skill test on type in accordance with UK Part-FCL (UK CAA Certificated Examiner on UK CAA approved simulator).